# lsof show many sock fd while ss/netstat does not show

Tags: linux, bash, file, sockets, tcp

My server error about `socket: too many open files`, then I use ss/netstat to see tcp connections, just a few results, while lsof gives a lot results, why this happen? I alse found they exsits in /proc/self/fd dir.
[image]

Comment: A socket will not show up as connection if it is not connected.

Comment: You mean those fd has never been connected? But ss/netstat can show SYNC_RECV states, right?

Comment: I have never met this before.

Comment: There is basically nothing known about your setup and what application has the sockets open. It is easy to create a socket which is not connected.

Answer (score 0):

The output depends on the flags that you use with commands.
Also, AFAIK `netstat` does not show udp sockets.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your reminding, but I do use option to show all socket, aka, netstat -antp and ss -apn.

Comment: -t for `ss` and for `netstat` in linux means TCP, so probably, they do not show udp, unix sockets and so on.

Comment: Well, I know this.The picture above is missing. Lsof show those fd's are TCP.

Comment: I built this program through static linked glibc on Ubuntu, while run it on a Centos machine, maybe this could be the problem.

Comment: @kingkong did these "sock" entries have anything to do with "too many open files" error?